# An easy way for a client to update HTML tags (not content contained within the tags...)?

Tags: html, content-management-system, tags, editing

I have a 6 month calendar set up for my client (a B&B operator).  When dates become unavailable, I simply change my tags to include a CSS class.  For example, if I want to mark the 5th and 6th as booked, I change the code like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td class="no">5</td>
    <td class="no">6</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
   ....
  </tr>
</table>
```

Easy enough.  But my client would like to be able to make these updates on her own, and I'm not sure how to set her up to do this.  I've looked at Content Management Systems, but it seems that those are set up to change content within an HTML tag, and not the tag itself.

Any  advice is very appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Javascript! With JQuery.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835440/jquery-changing-css-class-to-div, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918792/use-jquery-to-change-an-html-tag, http://www.jquery4u.com/dynamic-css-2/change-css-jquery/

Comment: I think the above suggestions are probably not that useful as I believe the OP wants to save the changes permanently.

Comment: Is the calendar data stored somewhere?  If that data was in a database table and you had a field flagging dates that were booked you could add the class when you output the table.

Which cms are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer, it's likely going to be over your head for the moment (no offense intended).

What you're asking is going to require knowledge of a back-end language like PHP or ASP, a database (with knowledge of how to access it - often MySQL), and an understanding of many security related things like authentication/authorization, SQL injection...etc.

If you're not in a rush for this to be done, you can start learning PHP/MySQL as a starting point.  Doing a CMS like this is not the easiest first-time PHP projects though - just a heads up... there are a lot of things you may not think about for data integrity, security...etc

If you are in a rush, **likely your best bet moving forward** is to either find another developer with the above knowledge or **start looking through CMS options** to see what's available in them:  http://spyrestudios.com/free-content-management-systems/ (there may be a calendar plugin for some that allow you to do what you're asking).

---

**Doing it yourself explanation:**

After dealing with user logins...etc, you'll probably want to make a front-end calendar that allows the user to click a date, and select options - this can be done with html/css/javascript.  When they select an option for a date, you can Ajax it to a file that processes the data into a database to store which dates have selected options.  Then, when displaying the calendar on the front end, just compare against the database and write the option(s) as a class, or as data, or anything else you want.

This is a very general/fast explanation, as it's going to vary GREATLY depending upon needs. (and this question is listed as HTML/CSS anyway.

Comment: the fastest and best way will probably be to take a look at various CMS systems. There are few small and light-weight systems out there. Most of them have some kind of integrated (JavaScript based) HTML Editor for the users to enter/update content

Comment: Cypherabe - agree.  Other than finding someone else to do it.  I'll bold that part of the answer.

Comment: For now, I am researching different CMS systems.  One of these days, I will get down to really learning PHP and creating a database (or databases) to store my information.  Thanks to all for the advice :)